# Is there a detailed overview of netty benchmarks and what they're doing?

Tags: netty

I've ran the benchmarks Netty provides but I don't fully understand what these tests are doing. Is there a detailed overview of these benchmarks? I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the contributors of Netty benchmarks and the answer is no: AFAIK there is no description about what they do and why.
I suggest to read https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/tree/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples to better understand why they are written in such way, but each single benchmark must be carefully read and analysed to understand what is meant to test.
Luckily naming and package location often suggest what's the purpose of each benchmark.

Comment: okay, thanks. Are there benchmarks that compare the performance of NIO transports with OIO?

Comment: The microbenchmarks won't perform such kind of end to end/high-level tests: there are few echo examples, but there are no metrics ie latencies/throughput. I suggest to use some load generator framework or just modify some of these test to match what your application logic is supposed to do in order to verify which one suit better for you. Personally I would go for NIO unless you have a have more connections then actual cores in your machine.